# Windows Forms Chart series X values always zero

Tags: windows, forms, charts

I am working on a simple Windows Forms chart example which produces an XY scatter plot.  The code that generates and binds the data for the plot as follows:

```
    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Xvals"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Yvals"));

        for (i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Xvals"] = i*2;
            dr["Yvals"] = i * i;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Xvals";
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Yvals";
        chart1.DataSource = dt;
        chart1.DataBind();

         DataPointCollection dpc = chart1.Series[0].Points;      

    }
```

This works as expected and the graph displays with the correct X an Y values.  However, if I later try look up values in the series (to get the Y value associated with an X position on the chart), I discover that all the DataPoints in the series Points collection have X=0 (the Y values are OK).

This very strange since the data is actually plotted with the correct X axis values. Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Comment: Show the code that fails

Comment: Why does one of the `char1.Series[0]` end in `Member` and the other end in `Members`?